# Updating WordPress Breaks custom Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-theme

We have a custom developed theme that gets broken with a 500 Error when updating to the latest WordPress.

I am receiving this error in the log file:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_iterable() (previously declared in 
/home/smartservice/dev.smartservice.com/wp-includes/compat.php:536) in 
/home/smartservice/dev.smartservice.com/wp- 
content/themes/smartservice/custom_functions.php on line 40
```

I’m unfamiliar with Php to this extent and i've heard it's outdated. We are running PHP 7.0 on the current site that this error is on.

The code for these lines are
- custom-function.php
compact.php

```
function is_iterable ( $var ) {
return ( is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By below code it will clear this error.

```
if(!function_exists('is_iterable'){
    function is_iterable ( $var ) {
        return ( is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. This is because the `is_iterable` function was added in PHP 7.0 (and as a sidenote does the exact same thing that OP's function does). You can't redeclare native functions. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php

Comment: Yes that is the reason and above code with handle that situation well

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. Much appreciate it!

Comment: Here is the line of full code line
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_iterable' ) ) {
 /**
  * Polyfill for is_iterable() function added in PHP 7.1.
  *
  * Verify that the content of a variable is an array or an object
  * implementing the Traversable interface.
  *
  * @since 4.9.6
  *
  * @param mixed $var The value to check.
  *
  * @return bool True if `$var` is iterable, false otherwise.
  */
 function is_iterable( $var ) {
  return ( is_array( $var ) || $var instanceof Traversable );
 }
}

Tried to switch out the code it still breaks the theme.

Comment: Could you explain how this fix's my issue? It seems to be just a duplicate of the code that I have

Comment: What will be the problem if you remove it from the functions.php